# Referencing a value in a particular named column

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an excel formula/VBA script to reference a cell value in a column with a particular column name?

For example: Multiply value in column "# of fruit" with value in column "price of fruit" in this row.

Normally this is easily done with cell references but I need it to be done using particular column names, as the column could be in different places in different worksheets.  I want to code this into a user defined function so it can be used regardless of where the columns are as long as the header name is the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's not how things are done in Excel.  Certainly you **can** do that by executing a search from within your function for that header and then act on the cells below it.  but why would you design a spreadsheed with roaming column headers.  Typically you would use Named Ranges and they would represent a fixed location within the workbook.  but they can be anywhere and the function would always use the RangeName regardless of where it's been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as I imagine with "column name" you mean the first cell of a column, you might perform a search into a user function as you say and then perform the operation:

```
Public Function myOperation(ByVal columnHeader1 As String, ByVal columnHeader2 As String) As Long

    'note: if you want to hardcode the values, you just need to remove the arguments from the brackets above and uncomment the following two lines of code: 

    'columnHeader1 = "# of fruits"
    'columnHeader2 = "price of fruit"      

    cnt1 = 1
    cnt2 = 1
    Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(1,cnt1).Value <> columnHeader1
        cnt1 = cnt1 + 1
    Loop     
    Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(1,cnt2).Value <> columnHeader2
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1
    Loop   
    myOperation = ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, cnt1).Value*ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row,cnt2).Value
End Function
```

In that case, you would need to type into a cell the formula:

```
=myOperation("# of fruit", "price of fruit")
```

and this will return, in that cell, the product between the two at the same line (I let you manage the customizations). Please note that you will need an error handling (if you enter a non existing name you risk to enter in an endless loop, refer to Christmas007 answer for how to trap if the Find has actually found something).

**EDIT**

I have replaced `ActiveCell` with `Application.Caller`, to make the formula dynamically responding to the caller cell in which the function lies.

This is how the hardcoded values function looks like:

```
Public Function myOperation() As Long

    columnHeader1 = "# of fruits"
    columnHeader2 = "price of fruit"

    cnt1 = 1
    cnt2 = 1
    Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cnt1).Value <> columnHeader1
        cnt1 = cnt1 + 1
    Loop
    Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cnt2).Value <> columnHeader2
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1
    Loop
    myOperation = ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, cnt1).Value * ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, cnt2).Value
End Function
```

and it is called with a simple `=myOperation()` into the cell.

Comment: this is excellent! Each row now calculates individually.  I was not able to hardcode the values though.  I removed the arguments so the first line reads:

Public Function myOperation() As Long

removed both comments for "columnHeader (1 and 2).

I'm calling the function by "=myOperation()"

What am I doing wrong?  Thank for your superb help with this!

Comment: @MMJ please see edit, I don't think you're doing something wrong. Remember to accept the answer if it works, and that you can/should upvote all the contents that you find useful (not only the one that you select as an answer).

Comment: done like a boss!  Thank you very much.  Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, I am going to include @fnostro's answer from his comment which is spot on...

> "That's not how things are done in Excel. Certainly you can do that by executing a search from within your function for that header and then act on the cells below it. but why would you design a spreadsheed with roaming column headers. Typically you would use Named Ranges and they would represent a fixed location within the workbook. but they can be anywhere and the function would always use the RangeName regardless of where it's been defined."

However, you could do this using a search:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ColNum As Long, LastCol As Long

    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If Not Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol)).Find("# of Fruit", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        ColNum = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol)).Find("# of Fruit", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    Else
        MsgBox "'# of Fruit' Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

`ColNum` would then be your reference to that column.

Edit:  Forgot to include an error handler if the `.Find` returned `Nothing`.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. The spreadsheet is auto-generated from a system and several users insert columns before it gets to me.  These columns are randomly inserted so can't use Named Ranges.  I only want to pick up values in two columns - regardless of where they are located in the sheet.

Matteo NNZ: your solution worked - but only for one row.  Copying the function down gives the same result as it did for the first row (after the column headers.)

Also, can the "# of fruit" and the "price of fruit" be hard-coded into the function?  These column headers will not change.

Comment: @MMJ my code will return the column number... Is that sufficient?

Comment: @MMJ, don't write the comments into someone else's answer or I won't receive any notification, I have seen your comment by chance ;) Check it out now, I have modified `ActiveCell` with `Application.Caller` which is what you wanted, now it should work as you expected.